# Shadowbind Ritual and Spirit-Ridden

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, rituals, werewolf-the-forsaken-2e

Can a Shadowbind ritual bind a Spirit-Ridden: Claimed, Possessed or Urged human?

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] to learn about the site. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 1):

Shadowbind Rite (p.141) says:

> The rite targets a single spirit that is present on the same side of the Gauntlet. The participants must define a binding space that the spirit is currently within.

So, it doesn't bind human, but it can bind spirit.

Now, let's check each of those conditions:

**Urged** (p.190):

> This animal or human host has been used as a Fetter by a
> spirit.

Which leads us to 'Fettered' (p. 190) condition:

> The spirit has secured itself to an object or creature. As
> long as it remains Fettered, the spirit is safe from Essence
> bleed. The spirit remains in Twilight and must stay within five
> yards of the Fetter.

Spirit and human are not the same and thus using shadowbind on *human* won't do anything. Still, werewolves can detect spirits in Twilight (p. 95), so they can target the spirit itself if it doesn't hide well. Or large enough binding area would be able to contain spirit. You may want to consult with your Storyteller, whether they accept 'know that it's somewhere within this zone' as 'targetting spirit'

**Possessed** condition says (p.190-191):

> This object, corpse, or living being is temporarily controlled by a spirit. Living hosts are put into a coma-like state while being possessed — they experience the possession as missing time, except for flashbacks that might come out in dreams or times of stress such as losing Integrity.

and

> To possess a host, the spirit must remain in Twilight, superimposed over the host. This means that if the host touches the spirit’s bane or is injured by a weapon made of the bane, the spirit will suffer wounds to its Corpus.

Spirit and host are still not the same, so targetiing *human* won't help. Still, with thise condition, Spirit is quite obvious and easy to locate, as it can't hide inside the host.

**Claimed**:

> A Claimed object, corpse, creature, or person is permanently possessed and merges with the spirit involved. Unlike victims of Possess, a living Claimed isn’t put into a fugue state, but remains mentally active while his soul and the Claiming spirit merge together over the course of several days.

At this point - human host and spirit are one and while spirit can attempt to abandon its host - it's not that easy. Thus I'd say that resulting hybrid is part spirit and can be held by shadowbind targetting it.